# How do I numerically solve a custom function?

Tags: functions, numerics

Whenever I use functions like `FindRoot` or `NDSolve`, it sends `x` through the function and deals with the result. That would be fine if I was sending a simple math function through, but I have something more like a short program. Is there any way to make it solve it by putting specific values through the function and looking at the results?

Comment: You can give a program as a function to FindRoot. Just be sure to restric the arguments to numerical values, e.g. programF[x_?NumberQ] := ...; FindRoot[programF[x]==0,{x,1}].

Comment: What do I do about passing arrays?

Comment: That's a bit vague. Could you maybe talk about your *actual problem*, so we can be more helpful?

Comment: To pass array try programF[x_?(ArrayQ[#, _, NumericQ] &)] := ...;

Comment: @Plato, or `x_ /; ArrayQ[x, _, NumericQ]`...

Comment: @J.M. U r right. However any cool trick from your bag to check if the array entries are either $1$ or $0$ not only just the `NumericQ`. In other words on a general note how to replace the `NumericQ` in my `x_?(ArrayQ[#, _, NumericQ] &)` with any other custom test function.

Comment: @Plato, like `x_ /; ArrayQ[x, _, MatchQ[#, 0 | 1] &]` then?

Comment: I tested out the programF[x_?NumberQ] thing on a function designed to print out the arguments passed to it. It's still just printing out a variable name. My actual program involves taking a slice of a 3d triple bubble, doing a circular inversion over a point, and taking a circular inversion of one of the borders. It's not something that would work if you tried to just run "x" through it.

Comment: Odd. It seems to work now. I'm not sure what I changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you a simple but realistic example. Imagine you are given two $d$-dimensional vectors $X$ and $B$. Now you are asked to find a matrix say $A$ such that $AX=B.$ How can we use *Mathematica* to solve this problem?

Prepare the two vectors `X` and `B`

```
d = 6;
SeedRandom[123];
X = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, d];
B = RandomReal[{200, 400}, d];
```

Now is time to define a function that takes a numerical $d\times d$-dimensional array $A$ as input and computes the norm $|A X-B|.$

```
Obj[A_?(ArrayQ[#, _, NumericQ] &)] := (A. X - B) // Norm;
```

At this point one would try to minimize the above function in order to get the matrix $A$ such that $AX=B$ holds approximately. We use the `FindMinimum` function with a derivative free method option.

```
FindMinimum[Obj[A], {A, RandomReal[{1, 25}, {d, d}]},
Method -> "PrincipalAxis", AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 60,
MaxIterations -> 1000] // Short
```

> {1.39237*10^-13,{A->{{-66.9631,20.7114,14.3336,11.7857,9.99711,14.8347},{-<<19>>,<<4>>,<<19>>},<<3>>,{<<1>>}}}}

Similar things can be done for functions like `FindRoot` or `NDSolve`. Hope this helps.

BR

Comment: This works, but when I tried to modify it to use a real number (replacing (ArrayQ[#, _, NumericQ] &) with NumberQ) or even a one dimensional array (I just changed the program so it uses one dimensional arrays and set the initial point to one) it started sending variables through again. Also, taking out the ?(ArrayQ[#, _, NumericQ] &) part also resulted in that. Am I modifying it wrong? I need to run these sorts of functions with a real number and a one dimensional array.

Comment: Never mind. It seems to work fine now.